# Issue with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Recently our ruby on rails application was upgraded to 2.3.8. We also replaced Mongrel/Mongrel cluster with Phusion Passenger during upgrade.

Whenever we try to deploy our application, it seems to be responding faster initially but response time gradually increases. We also noticed that cpu usage on the database box spiking to 400% and lot of requests waiting in global queue. This seems to be happening only in our production environment.

Can anyone let me know how I should go about debugging this issue?

Is there anyway we can restrict the number of connections between passenger and DB?

Also is there a way we can setup connection pooling in passenger?

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue is with Passenger. If you are having a large spike on your DB box CPU, your issue probably lies there. Without more information about your database it's hard to give you specifics, but here are a few things you could try:

1. Run `top` and check how much of your total memory the mysqld or other database process is consuming. If this amount is not high then you probably need to tune MySQL settings to take advantage of the RAM on your DB box.
2. Analyze your running database queries with the `mytop` command. You might have some queries that are hogging all of your system resources or causing lots of swapping.
3. Look through your MySQL slow log and see if you have queries that are taking over 1 second to run.
4. Check your database engines. Are you using MYISAM and/or InnoDB? You might need to tune your database differently so that it can allocate the proper amount of memory and resources to each engine.
5. Consult a DBA. They'll be able to take a look at your usage and application and tell you more definitively if the issue lies with your database or application.

P.S: I would recommend upgrading to Passenger 3, it performs better than Passenter 2.

Comment: I second the upgrade to passenger 3.0.x.

Comment: We are already using passenger 3. We are running the application on six machines with each machine having 45 instances of passenger. So i guess a total of 270 connections gets opened with MySQL. Could this be the reason why mysql is hogging the CPU? Will restricting the number of connections with mysql help in anyway?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I would recommend checking the steps I outlined in my answer first. 45 instances of passenger seems like a lot for a single machine, but if they can handle it, the more power to you. You could try limiting the passenger deamons that you have open.